# How to do the interlaced rendering effect

Tags: opengl, glsl

How to do interlaced( an output where we draw a line and we skip (or darken) the next and so on) rendering effect in opengl.

I have read that we can use the stencil buffer to mask the lines.Every odd line fill with 1 in stencil

But i am not able to figure out the code for it  , if someone can please show me how this can be done.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Andreas That is the problem i am not able to figure out how this can be done.

Comment: Then do your research, show your attempts, the current output, and what is the expected result

Comment: @Andreas After doing my research i found out that this can be done via stencil buffer.

Comment: But i am not able to figure out how we can do it for alternate lines.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are struggling with? Setting up the stencil buffer? Filling it? Using it for rendering?

Comment: @Nico Schertler how can I set it for alternate lines.

Comment: Use a fragment shader to draw a full-screen quad. In the fragment shader, set every second line to transparent (using `gl_FragCoord`). Alternatively, you can do it without the stencil buffer via a post-process (bind your current screen as input texture and draw a full-sceen quad; in the fragment shader, do whatever you want with the lines).